# Why is Unreal Engine Blueprint Editor so slow?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

Blueprint Editor is extremely slow on my Ubuntu 16.04. Can I improve performance without upgrading?

[image: Screenfetch]
[image: Blueprint Editor]

Answer (score 5):

The poor performance in the widget editor appears to be a bug. However, keep in mind that your system does not meet the recommended specs suggested by Epic for developing using the engine;

```
Desktop PC or Mac
Windows 7 64-bit or Mac OS X 10.9.2 or later
Quad-core Intel or AMD processor, 2.5 GHz or faster
NVIDIA GeForce 470 GTX or AMD Radeon 6870 HD series card or higher
8 GB RAM
```

Your best course of action is to file a detailed bug report with Epic to fix this specific issue, and consider upgrading for the long term.

Src: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Recommended_Hardware

Comment: +1, in particular a GeForce 630M, despite the higher model number, is a *significantly* weaker GPU than the recommended: http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-630M.63761.0.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug due to FNullSourceCodeAccessor::CanAccessSourceCode() being called too often.

There is a fix that has been applied to 4.17, and you can manually add it to your code by applying the changes found here.

https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/commit/dbd864dc2de889a87a5b5a1d4d0c7cb58249c372